# IE8 Crashes When Drawing LineChart -- All Other Browsers Work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

We've been building an application using the [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index). Everything works in most of our supported browsers, but IE8 is causing issues. Technically the browser does not crash, the charts simply take so long to render that the browser thinks it is crashing and warns that the script should be stopped. When we allow the script to complete, rendering the chart has taken **minutes** to fully render. In Chrome, FF, and IE9 the charts are rendered instantly. This large discrepancy between browsers might indicate an issue on Google's end, but given that Googling the issue did not turn up much by way of similar issues, I can't help but think we are handling something incorrectly on our end.

The following is the method we are using to generate the chart and everything is hanging at the `chart.draw` call.

```
function drawChart(data) {
    var options = {
        title: 'Occupancy and Volume History',
        isStacked: true,
        colors: ['#0066FF', '#53CF53', '#E0440E', '#E6693E', '#FF9900', '#009933'],
        hAxis: { format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:SS a',
            gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }
        },
        vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: Number('0'),
            max: Number('0.96')
        },
            gridlines: { color: 'transparent'}
        },
        pointSize: 5,
        series: { 4: { pointSize: 0 },
            5: { pointSize: 0 }
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The data is being retrieved and processed like so:

```
$.post(<path to data>,
    function (data) {
        // Format date to actual date object
        $.each(data.rows, function (i, row) {
            data.rows[i].c[0].v = new Date(row.c[0].v);
        });

        drawChart(data);
});
```

A sample of the data being built server-side and passed to the above method can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/4v8UcMmk). Before the data is passed into the method, the date strings are converted to JavaScript Date objects. All other data is left as is.

In our HTML we're preventing IE compatibility mode and we've verified that the browser is respecting this and is rendering in IE8 mode, we're using the HTML5 doctype (ie: `DOCTYPE html`), and we're using a bare `html` element to start the document.

If any further information is needed, I'm happy to give it.

**EDIT: Data being used was previously malformed. Link to [sample data](http://pastebin.com/4v8UcMmk) has been modified to link to new corrected format which still presents same issues.**

**EDIT 2: arrayToDataTable is no longer being used after fixing the data structure.**

**EDIT 3: Added retrieval and processing of data prior to calling `drawChart()`.**

Comment: One huge question... Why are you developing for IE8 still? A number of online resources state that (on average) only 5% still use IE8... do you or your client have a specific requirement for IE8?

Comment: Unfortunately, our client is still on IE8 for a majority of machines.

Comment: You can try the HTML5shiv fix to see if you see any better results for the rendering... - https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: @BigChris, we don't actually have anything HTML5-specific on the page (despite the HTML5 doctype), but thanks! We actually think we may have tracked down the issue... The data we're generating is malformed based on this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable

Comment: The `arrayToDataTable` function won't work with your data structure, you need to use the standard `DataTable` constructor: `var gdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);`.

Comment: @asgallant, You are absolutely right. Unfortunately, I just forgot to remove that from the question after we fixed the data being passed in. In our current code we no longer use arrayToDataTable and the issue persists. I've edited the question accordingly and apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is `data` the json string, or have you already converted it to a DataTable at that point?

Comment: @asgallant It is already a `DataTable` when it reaches the method.

Comment: Can you update your question with the function you are using to do the ate conversion and DataTable creation?

Comment: @asgallant Sorry, yes I should have included that. I've just added that information.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use the string-to-date conversion that Date objects provide.  This function is inconsistent across browsers, and even with the same browser, users in different locales will parse date strings differently.  As an example:

```
new Date('06-08-2014')
```

might parse as June 8, 2014 to a user in the US, but August 6, 2014 to a user in Europe.

You should manually parse your date strings appropriately.  I will assume for this example that your date strings are in the format `'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss A'`.  Parse the date string like this:

```
$.each(data.rows, function (i, row) {
    var match = row.c[0].v.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (..)/);
    var year = parseInt(match[3], 10);
    var month = parseInt(match[1], 10) - 1; // adjust for javascript's 0-indexed months
    var day = parseInt(match[2], 10);
    var hours = parseInt(match[4], 10) + (match[7] == 'AM' ? 0 : 12); // adjust hours for AM/PM
    var minutes = parseInt(match[5], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(match[6], 10);

    row.c[0].v = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
});
```

When you pass `data` to `drawChart`, it is still a raw object, not a proper DataTable.  You need to convert it to a DataTable object either before passing it to `drawChart` or in the `drawChart` function:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
```

Also, you should adjust your server code to output the numbers as numbers, not strings (eg, `"0"` should be `0`).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/a2uNj/